# Is $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (2x^2 +7)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to know about the ring $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (2x^2 +7)$$

Is $2$ is irreducible in  $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (2x^2 +7)$?

I want to know what is $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (2x^2 +7)$. Is $2$ of the form $2 + (2x^2 +7)$?

Please help me.

Comment: I think when you let $\eta=\sqrt{\frac72}i$, then $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (2x^2 +7)=\mathbb Z[\eta]$. then $2=2\eta^2-5$.

Comment: $2$ is a unit in this ring, since $-2(x^2+3)=1.$

Comment: @Nightflight $2=-2\eta^2-5,$ but I’m not sure how that helps OP.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All members of this quotient ring are of the form $a + bx +cx^2$, $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z$. When we multiply we can remove multiples of $2x^2+7$, or equivalently we can replace $2x^2$ by $-7$ (which BTW shows that $7$ is not irreducible as it equals $-2 \cdot x^2$ e.g. ). Try to write $2$ as a multiple of of such small polynomials and apply reductions and set equal some coefficients, maybe you'll get some ideas.....

Comment: I think your first statement is wrong. What is $x^3$ in this ring?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, thanks for your answer. I found that $ 2(x^2 + 4) = 2x^2 + 8 = 1$ because  $2x^2 + 8 = 1 (mod \ 2x^2 + 7)$. Am I right?

Comment: @user454229 Yes, that’s right but does that solve your question about $2$?

Comment: This answer is still wrong.